# Extract a number in each line and add another number to it

Tags: awk

I have a file whose content is

```
(bookmarks
 ("Cover"
  "#01.djvu" )
 ("Title page"
  "#all_24223_to_00243.cpc0002.djvu" )
 ("Preface"
  "#all_24223_to_00243.cpc0004.djvu" )
 ...
```

I want to change its content to be

```
(bookmarks
 ("Cover"
  "#2" )
 ("Title page"
  "#3" )
 ("Preface"
  "#5" )
...
```

by keeping the number just before `.djvu`, removing leading zeros, and adding one to it. I wonder how you would do that using awk?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. How does perl handle the testing for whether a line matches the pattern (if no, print the line, and if yes, replace, add and print)?

Comment: Thanks. I still don't know how -p make it print the lines without match, and print the lines with match after replacement. That is, why is there no explicit testing each line if it has any match. In awk, I remember such testing is needed.

Comment: Additionally, if I store a number in a shell variable, and want to add it to the extracted number of each line, how can I pass the shell variable into the `perl` command to be added to `$1`?

Answer (score 5):

That's more a job for `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/"#\K.*?(\d+)\.djvu(?=")/$1+1/ge' <file
```

With variable:

```
INCR=1 perl -pe 's/"#\K.*?(\d+)\.djvu(?=")/$1+$ENV{INCR}/ge' <file
```

Or:

```
perl -spe 's/"#\K.*?(\d+)\.djvu(?=")/$1+$incr/ge' -- -incr=1 <file
```

Comment: could also use positive lookahead to avoid adding the quote back in replacement section..

Comment: @Sundeep, true, that makes it a bit shorter and more pleasant to the eye. I've added it in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GNU `awk` solution:

```
awk  '/^ *\(/{print}!/^ *\(/{split($1,aa,"[0-9]+",bb);printf "\"#%s\" )\n", bb[length(bb)]+1}'
```

or the identical, but spread over a few lines for readability:

```
awk  '/^ *\(/ { print }
     !/^ *\(/ { split( $1, aa, "[0-9]+", bb )
                printf "\"#%s\" )\n", bb[length(bb)]+1 }'
```

1. `/^ *\` and `!/^ *\(/` are two address rules, covering lines beginning with optional spaces and an open parenthesis ... and lines that don't.
2. `split( $1, aa, "[0-9]+", bb )` For lines that don't, split the line into two arrays. `aa` is the line content delimited by the regex "[0-9]+", and `bb` are the delimiters that matched the regex. The final element of `bb` is what interests you.
3. `printf "\"#%s\" )\n"` formats the output line, waiting for a single variable...
4. `bb[length(bb)]+1` one plus the value of the last element of bb.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '{
    sub(/#.*\.djvu/, "#" $1 + 1 ".djvu")
    print
}' FPAT='[0-9]+\.djvu' input.txt
```

The idea is following:

- extract the `.djvu` extension with leading numbers from the `djvu` filename, using the `[0-9]+\.djvu` pattern (`FPAT`). **Example**: original filename is `#all_24223_to_00243.cpc0002.djvu`, the extracted part will be `0002.djvu`.
- substitute the previous `djvu` filename `#.*\.djvu` to the extracted one, increasing it by `1` previously. **Example**: take whole line `$0` and substitute `#all_24223_to_00243.cpc0002.djvu` inside it, to the `0002.djvu + 1` (this expression results to the plain number `3`, because of how the string to number conversion works in the `gawk`). Add the `#` sign and `.djvu` extension to it. **Result**: `#3.djvu`.

This solution will work only for lines with one `djvu` filename, as in your sample input.

**Input**

```
(bookmarks
 ("Cover"
  "#01.djvu" )
 ("Title page"
  "#all_24223_to_00243.cpc0002.djvu" )
 ("Preface"
  "#all_24223_to_00243.cpc0004.djvu" )
```

**Output**

```
(bookmarks
 ("Cover"
  "#2.djvu" )
 ("Title page"
  "#3.djvu" )
 ("Preface"
  "#5.djvu" )
```